Cauchy problem of nonlinear PDE with a weird condition
Let $u=u(x,t)$ be the solution of the Cauchy problem
$\partial u/\partial t$$ +(\partial u/\partial x)^2=1, x\in \mathbb R, t>0$.
$u(x,0)=-x^2,x\in \mathbb R$.

(I) Using Charpit's method, the solution is :
$u(x,t)=ax+(1-a^2)t+b$ where $a,b\in \mathbb R$
On imposing the given condition i.e. $u(x,0)=-x^2$ on this solution renders something like 
$ax+b=-x^2$
which leads me to nowhere.


(II) I tried the substitution $u(x,t)=-x^2.f(t)$ in the given PDE but that gives an equation of the form:
$f'(t)-4f^2(t)=-1/x^2$
to which I am really afraid considering a feasible ODE either. Even though if I treat $x$ as constant (which I suspect to do actually) then the solution to it is:
$f(t)=\frac{e^{4xt}(2x-1)+(2x+1)}{2x[(2x+1)-e^{4xt}(2x-1)]}$
so that
$u(x,t)=-x^2\left(\frac{e^{4xt}(2x-1)+(2x+1)}{2x[(2x+1)-e^{4xt}(2x-1)]}\right)$

Please verify which is correct and is there any other approach to solve this problem? Thanks!!!

The solution that you found using Charpit's method is called a complete integral$^{(*)}$ of the PDE. It contains as many arbitrary constants as the number of independent variables, but one cannot, in general, choose them in order to satisfy the initial condition. It is possible, however, to use the complete integral to construct a solution that satisfies it. Here are the steps:

From the two-parameter family of solutions
$$
u(x,t)=ax+(1-a^2)t+b \tag{1}
$$
we select those that are tangent to the curve $\tilde{u}(x,0)=-x^2$ in the plane $t=0$:
$$
u(x,0)=\tilde{u}(x,0) \implies ax+b=-x^2, \tag{2}
$$
$$
u_x(x,0)=\tilde{u}_x(x,0) \implies a=-2x. \tag{3}
$$
Eliminating $x$ from $(2)$ and $(3)$, we get
$$
b=\frac{a^2}{4}. \tag{4}
$$
Plugging $(4)$ into $(1)$, we obtain the one-parameter family of solutions
$$
u(x,t)=ax+(1-a^2)t+\frac{a^2}{4}. \tag{5}
$$

Now we have to find the envelope of this family of solutions. To accomplish this, we have to eliminate the parameter $a$ from $(5)$ and the equation
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial a}=0
\implies x-2at+\frac{a}{2}=0. \tag{6}
$$
Solving $(6)$ for $a$ and plugging the result into $(5)$, we finally obtain
$$
u(x,t)=t+\frac{x^2}{4t-1}. \tag{7}
$$



$^{(*)}$ See, for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_partial_differential_equation.
